# Access denied error on php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have 3 php files to connect phpmyadmin database.

Content of /Android/db_connect.php:

```
<?php

/**

 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

Content of /Android/db_config.php:

```
  <?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "u155019120_movie"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "xxxxxxxxx"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "u155019120_movie"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "mysql.hostinger.web.tr"); // db server
?>
```

Content of /publichtml/get_all_products:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/../Android/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

When i open http://moviestolike.pe.hu/get_all_products.php page (also you can view), it says

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u155019120/Android/db_connect.php on line 28
{"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"sogan","price":"19.30","created_at":"2016-03-12 15:08:38","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"pid":"2","name":"faltak","price":"22.00","created_at":"2016-03-12 15:08:38","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"success":1}
```

it gives right products. But when i change the deprecated method as

```
  // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
```

in first file i wrote here, the output is

```
    Deprecated: mysql_select_db(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u155019120/Android/db_connect.php on line 31
Access denied for user ''@'10.2.1.37' to database 'u155019120_movie'
```

What is wrong? I don't even know what 10.2.1.37 is. My username is what i wrote here.

Also i cant change mysql_select to mysqli_select, it wants one more parameter.

Comment: you need to move on to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` completely. because `mysql_*` is deprecated library now. Also `$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());` or you can use `mysqli_select_db()`seperatly. Don't mix both `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Will not work, gives you lot of pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax for mysqli_connect

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

port and socket fields are optional you can ignore those two by using it as

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
```

Comment: still some problem exist.